# Two hamburger Menu Bars

Tags: navigation, design, hamburger

The issue is having two hamburger menu bars.
Would burger menu combined with tabs be better suited for this menu section.

- Menu bar #1 appears when user logs in.
- Menu bar #2 is for all customers (logged in or not) and is intended to help user navigate to products to shop/purchase.

Having it in tabs might be distracting, but if it's hidden they might not know it's there. We intend to shorten the amount of links when logged in to 4.

Logged In:

[image: Logged In]

Menu bar #1 appears when user logs in:

[image: Menu#1]

Menu bar #2 appears for all customers (logged in or not):

[image: Menu#2]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In my view, these were not two hamburger menus, but rather (A) search and (B) profile functions.
So I will organize it this way.

(A) Search.
If the search function is already out there, users will notice it right away. Also, cart/favorites/notifications should be placed together in the same section as action elements.
These elements will serve as core interactions within this site.

(B) Profile
Accumulated points/titles directly related to the user will be grouped together in the same location. Also, the 3-line and down arrow actions should not be mixed. Also, assuming that right-handed users will exceed the majority of the population, it would be a good idea to group the action functions on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I agree that it's questionable. Especially when they're in such close proximity. I would at least move the user one to the right side.

But does the search one really need to have a hamburger design? That seems pretty unique. What happens when I click on it -- a search or a filters screen or what? Maybe that's the icon that should change to reflect what it does. The user one seems pretty well matched to its purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would move the second menu to the top right corner and make an avatar icon instead of the menu. As I understand it, all sections that inside belong to the user option, so they should be marked as personal options.

In addition, I would redo the top bar. Favorites made the same inside the user's list, would hide notifications. Since they are often not needed, or very rarely work. I do not think that you will often send news or promotions to the client, and therefore it is worth bringing them to the fore.

And I would have made the burger menu on the whole screen, so there is more space and it is easier to work with information.